# Cleanly handling TypeErrors of multiple variables

Tags: python, error-handling, code-structure

Currently I am working on a webapp, where I came across the problem, that a function has to handle multiple inputs, but any number of them could be `None`(Or cause some other error for that matter):

```
def my_func(input_1: set, input_2: set, input_3: set): -> set
    return input_1 | input_2 | input_3
```

What would be the most elegant way of handling this? Just writing out all the cases would certainly be an option.

Looking forward to learning something and many Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, beware that explicitly declaring variable type on some webapps, like Flask will generate errors.
what I would do to manage types is :
`def my_func(input_1=None, input_2=None, input_3=None):`
    `if input_1 is None:`
        `#do something`
and same for other inputs. You can also test on types with :
`if type(input_2) is not set:
    `#do something`

Comment: @lalam Thanks for the tip about declaring types. I would have run head first into that in the next 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only case is that the inputs may be `None` you can assign empty `set()` instead of `None`:

```
def my_func(input_1: set, input_2: set, input_3: set) -> set:
    inputs = (
        input_1 or set(), 
        input_2 or set(),
        input_3 or set()
    )

    return set.union(*inputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it the brute force way by typing out all the of the cases:

```
def my_func(input_1, input_2, input_3):
    types = (
        type(input_1),
        type(input_2),
        type(input_3),
        )

    if not all(types):
        return None
    elif not (types[0] and types[1]):
        return input_3
    elif not (types[0] and types[2]):
        return input_2
    elif not (types[1] and types[2]):
        return imput_1
    elif not types[0]:
        return input_2 | input_3
    elif not types[1]:
       return input_1 | input_3
    elif not types[2]:
        return input_1 | input_2
    else:
        return input_1 | input_2 | input_3
```

Unfortunately this will fail with more inputs being used, sice one needs to handle 2^(num_inputs) cases, so I'm open to better suggestions.